# Woo-commerce : Fatal error: Call to undefined method wpdb::esc_like()

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

thank you so much all of you to help us..

I have installed a theme woo-commerce in wordpress but showing as error like that

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method wpdb::esc_like() in /customers/2/6/c/xyz.in/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-install.php on line 202
```

so how can i resolve this issues, actually it's issues from the theme or database i am not getting the solution to resolve this..

Comment: Reinstall WP.  Just copy the core files.  You're missing some key files, which in turn are causing you to miss some key functions.

Comment: thank you to reply me, reinstal the wp or woo-commerce plugin

Comment: Reinstall WordPress (4.6)

Comment: but theme not support the wordpress (4.6) thats why m installing 3.9 so what should i do

Comment: **you should switch themes**.  Never, ever **ever** run old versions of WordPress.  Each version change improves security, and if you are running an old version of WP, you are inviting your site to be hacked.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce 2.6.6 requires Wordpress 4.4 or higher. If you want to use an old Wordpress like 3.9 (which a very bad idea, you should change your theme), try with old WooCommerce too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i think you are right Nikolay

Comment: This answer says it, but it is worth repeating: **you should switch themes** to one compatible with the latest version of WP.  Never, ever **ever** run old versions of WordPress.  Each version change improves security, and if you are running an old version of WP, you are inviting your site to be hacked.